# Reasons not to use TLS 1.3?

Tags: tls

I was learning about TLS 1.3 recently, and I was wondering if there are any reasons not to use it. (Rather stay at TLS 1.2). Are there are any factors that refrain users or products from making the change?

Comment: If you are running a server, you should absolutely use TLS 1.3 if possible.  But, you should also support TLS 1.2 (and possibly even older versions of TLS) if there will be clients connecting to your server that do not support TLS 1.3.

Comment: Older than TLS 1.2? I don’t see any reason for it. But support 1.2 & 1.3. Definitely.

Comment: Use TLS 1.3. Stop using TSL 1.2, there are very dangerous paths there. If some client needed to connect you TLS 1.2 then enforce them not to use CBC mode and non ephemeral modes...

Comment: For example one of the downgrade attacks [The 9 lives of Bleichenbacher's CAT, it puts another scratch again](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/64648/18298)

Comment: If a client is forced not to use CBC mode or non ephemeral modes in TLS 1.2, what modes are left available?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One could be if your company has applications in the intranet that may be old enough that they don't support TLS 1.3. The companies that developed these applications may not even exist anymore. But these applications may be important to the business.

That's why as long as there is a business need and as long as there is no replacement, you may need to keep TLS 1.2.

**Update:**

Example: There is a server application that only supports TLS 1.2. The vendor does not exist anymore. You have implemented a native client application that works with this server application. It makes no sense to add support of TLS 1.3 to the client, because the server will never support TLS 1.3. And if someday the server application is replaced with some other or with a couple of other applications, it may implement other workflows or processes and will require completely different native client, or may be it will be a web application. Talking about "coexistence" makes no sense in this context.

Comment: That's not really a reason not to use TLS 1.3, but instead a reason to keep TLS 1.2 around. Both 1.2 and 1.3 can coexist.